# List Squid's internal ip:port to external ip:port mapping table

Tags: squid

I'm assuming that squid keeps a list of internal ip:port that a request is made on and the matching external ip:port that the request is fulfilled with.

In the case of a long transfer, such as a file download, it would be nice to be able to see which internal ip:port is downloading the file.

I am able to see the traffic and get the external ip:port that squid is using easily with tcpdump or iptraf but I can't find a way to map this back to an internal ip:port.

Answer (score 1):

Squid's access.log should show you the requesting IP address. I use [SARG](http://sarg.sourceforge.net/) to parse access.log into something more readable. 
In the case that you want to know the requesting IP that goes with a specific file

```
grep *filename* access.log
```

...should tell you the requestor's/requestors' IP.